# JS Cascading dropdown showing index number instead of values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dropdown, html-select

I have a cascading dropdown that has two select dropdowns. Let's say, when I select Ariston in the first dropdown, it should show options "a, b, c, d" in the second dropdown. However, it is showing the index numbers of these options i.e. 0, 1, 2, and 3.

What should I change in my JS code so that the second dropdown would show the related values?

Screenshot of the dropdown showing indexes

[image]

```js
var brandObject = {
      'Ariston': ["a","b","c","d"],
      'Airpop': ["a","b"],
      }

window.onload = function() {
  var brandSel = document.getElementById("brand");
  var modelSel = document.getElementById("model");

  for (var x in brandObject) {
    brandSel.options[brandSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }

  brandSel.onchange = function() {
    modelSel.length = 1;  // empty 2nd dropdown

    for (var y in brandObject[this.value]) {
      modelSel.options[modelSel.options.length] = new Option(y,y);   
    }
  }    
}
```

```html
<select id="brand"></select>
<select id="model"></select>
```

Comment: Please add the html code so we that we could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the index that you got on the `y` variable to retrieve the value from your array `brandObject[this.value][y]`

```js
var brandObject = {
  'Ariston': ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  'Airpop': ["a", "b"],
}

window.onload = function() {
  var brandSel = document.getElementById("brand");
  var modelSel = document.getElementById("model");

  for (var x in brandObject) {
    brandSel.options[brandSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }

  brandSel.onchange = function() {
    modelSel.length = 1; // empty 2nd dropdown

    for (var y in brandObject[this.value]) {
      modelSel.options[modelSel.options.length] = new Option(brandObject[this.value][y], brandObject[this.value][y]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="brand">

</select>
<select id="model">

</select>
```